# How to correctly associate tables in sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to add associations to my defined tables and i am not sure if i have done it correctly. Basically i have a MySQL database that i want to re-create in sequelize as a second database.

MySQL tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS account(
   accountId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   password CHAR(60) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT usernameUnique UNIQUE (username)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS thread(
   threadId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   threadName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   threadOfAccount INTEGER NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY (threadOfAccount) REFERENCES account(accountId),
   CONSTRAINT threadNameUnique UNIQUE (threadName)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS post(
   postId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   postTitle VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   postContent TEXT NOT NULL,
   postOnThread INTEGER NOT NULL,
   postOfAccount INTEGER NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY (postOnThread) REFERENCES thread(threadId),
   FOREIGN KEY (postOfAccount) REFERENCES account(accountId),
   CONSTRAINT postTitleUnique UNIQUE (postTitle)
);
```

I have defined the tables identically in sequelize.
The associations added for the moment:

```
db.thread.associate = (models) => {
   this.thread.belongsTo(models.account, {
       foreignKey: 'threadOfAccount'
   })
}
db.thread.associate = (models) => {
   this.thread.hasMany(models.post)
}
db.post.associate = (models) => {
   this.post.belongsTo(models.thread, {
       foreignKey: 'postOnThread'
   })
}
db.post.associate = (models) => {
   this.post.belongsTo(models.account, {
       foreignKey: 'postOfAccount'
   })
}
```

When i make a db call conatining a LEFT JOIN using sequelize like below:

```
module.exports = function({ SQLiteDb }){
   return {
       getAllPosts: function(threadId, callback) {
           SQLiteDb.post.findAll({  
               include:[{
                   model:  SQLiteDb.thread, as: 'thread',
                   where: { postOnThread: threadId },
                   required: false,
               }], 
               raw: true 
           })
           .then(posts => callback([], posts))
           .catch(error => console.log(error, " ERRPR")
       }
    }
 }
```

I receive this error:
EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: thread is not associated to post!

Comment: did you solve ?

Comment: Hi! no it is not working, when I make a db call it says that thread is not associated with post...

Comment: you can check my github

Comment: I created test script, so, you can run `npm run test`

Comment: Yes, I checked your github. I have pretty much the same code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        post.belongsTo(models.thread, {
            foreignKey: 'postOnThread',
            as: 'thread',
        });
        post.belongsTo(models.account, {
            foreignKey: 'postOfAccount',
            as: 'account',
        });


        thread.belongsTo(models.account, {
            foreignKey: 'threadOfAccount',
            as: 'account',
        });
        thread.hasMany(models.post, {
            foreignKey: 'postOnThread',
            as: 'posts',
        });
```

Test

```
        const posts = await db.post.findAll({ include: ['account', 'thread'] });
        console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(posts)));

        const threads = await db.thread.findAll({ include: ['account', 'posts'] });
        console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(threads)));

        const accounts = await db.account.findAll({ include: ['account', 'posts'] });
        console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(accounts)));
```

We need call after `associate` definition

```
db.account.associate(db);
db.post.associate(db);
db.thread.associate(db);
```

Comment: https://github.com/nkhs/node-sequelize/tree/stack-68550869

Comment: I tried the test and this time i get the error: (node:194) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Association with alias "account" does not exist on post. The error occurr on "const posts = await db.post.findAll({ include: ['account', 'thread'] });"

Comment: on my side, it is working, what is your node version/sequelzie version ?

Comment: so, my project is not working on yor side?

Comment: send me the sqlite file, or, you are using mysql ?

Comment: i uploaded the whole project on dropbox, here is the link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5wvyu1xb5eko58c/closestqwest.zip?dl=0

Comment: what is the problem there?

Comment: https://github.com/nkhs/node-sequelize/tree/stack-68550869 : check the readme file

Comment: We need wait `await sequelize.authenticate();`,http://i.prntscr.com/pMYHegdESNGcQPb6onEhMg.png,

need call `db.account.associate(db);db.post.associate(db);db.thread.associate(db);`

Comment: oh thank you very much for your effort. I copy pasted the readme file but this time i receive another error saying: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: post.

Comment: i think it is occurring in `await db.post.create({
            postTitle: 'tt',
            postContent: 'wer',
            // postOnThread: 3,
            postOfAccount: a.id,
        });`

Comment: It WORKS! thank you a lot, you are a legend! i've been stuck with this forever..